# Scroll Disabled on setting scroll frame size again

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview

Hello friends i am very new to ios.
I am setting scroll size in view did load as

```
scrollView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460);
 [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320,500)];
```

now i want to scroll my frame up on clicking on button.

```
scrollView.frame=CGRectMake(0,-100, 320,550);
```

my frame moves up but after this my scroll view is disabled  i also tried using scrollview enabled but it also not works.

please suggest me Thanks in advance for your ans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set `[scrollView setContentOffset:animated:]` instead of setting `frame` to scroll. [Ref](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html)

In your case, you can probably do

```
[scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 100) animated:YES];
```

Comment: Hi barley tell me one more thing..I have made a register page which is on scroll view when i am clicking on text filed and resigning keyboard scroll disable tell me why  ???

Answer (score 2):

Because second time you're setting

```
scrollView.frame=CGRectMake(0,-100, 320,550);
```

in which 550 is `height` of `scrollView` and it is greater than its content height as you have set

```
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320,500)];
```

If you want to move your `scrollView` frame up on clicking on button then just decrease its **Y** co-ordinate dont increase its height. For vertical scrolling content height should be greater than frame height.
So second time set frame like this -

```
scrollView.frame=CGRectMake(0,-100, 320, 460);
```